# Unity C# Parse Query Problems

Tags: c#, parsing, unity-game-engine, parse-platform

I'm new to Parse and Facebook SDK's and when looking through the documentation and other posts I still can't get the query working. When using a query to get the data back from the server it isn't allowing me to put the information into variables. For example, when the code is called, all that appears in the console is: "Parse.ParseObject".

```
var query = ParseObject.GetQuery("DataRetrieval")
                .WhereEqualTo("RetrievalID", retrievalID);

query.FindAsync().ContinueWith(t =>
   {
        IEnumerable<ParseObject> createdAt = t.Result;
        foreach ( var obj in createdAt)
        {
            Debug.Log(obj);
            DateTime createdAtTime = obj.Get<DateTime>("createdAt");
            Debug.Log(createdAtTime);
            DateTime? updatedAt = dataRetrieval.UpdatedAt;
            Debug.Log(updatedAt);
        }
});
```

I've tried multiple different ways to get this to work. I'm also looking to retrieve data which I have stored, but I'm assuming that it will be done in the same/similar way to this once it's working.

Comment: What does “it isn't allowing me to put the information into variables” mean? You're getting some kind of error? Tell us the error. Also, what does the Unity Application Block have to do with your question?

Comment: Even though I'm using Debug.Log(); it only shows one "Parse.ParseObject" in the console when it should produce a DateTime.